# can someone suggest the most active software testing forum?

Tags: testing

can someone suggest the most active software testing forum ?

Comment: This is stackoverflow... superuser.com perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

Below are the few

http://www.qaforums.com/

http://www.onestoptesting.com/

http://www.sqaforums.com/ubbthreads.php

http://forum.onestoptesting.com/

Answer (score 1):

www.softwaretestingclub.com is a personal favorite of mine.

I would also suggest some discussion lists:

http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/agile-testing/

http://groups.yahoo.com/group/software-testing/

Good luck!